# HASKELL: listas por comprensión con dos funciones (eliminar elemento repetido)

Tags: programación-funcional, haskell

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
recorrido :: Int -> [Int] -> Int
recorrido _ [] = 0
recorrido x (y:ys) = if x/=y then recorrido x ys else (-1)

unique :: [Int] -> [Int]
unique [] = []
unique (x:xs) = [ x | x <- xs , recorrido x xs == 0]
```

La función ***unique*** recorre cada elemento de la lista, y con ***recorrido*** comparo el elemento con los demás elementos de la lista, buscando saber si ese elemento se repite o no. Si es 0, no se repite y se agrega en el resultado final, si se repite retorna -1.
Cuando compilo, aparentemente no hay errores, pero siempre me sale lista vacía:

```
PS C:\Users\CIEC\Documents\HASKELL> ghci 1.hs
GHCi, version 8.6.5: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( 1.hs, interpreted )
Ok, one module loaded.
*Main> unique [1,2,3]
[]
*Main> unique [1,1,1]
[]
*Main> unique [1,2,3,1]
[]
```

¿En que estoy fallando?

Comment: `recorrido x xs` siempre devolverá `-1` porque `x` es un miembro de `xs`. Por cierto, ¿porqué no `Bool`?

Comment: También probé con Bool, osea, reemplacé 0 y -1 por True y False, y el tipo de dato lo cambié, pero seguía igual. Y con respecto a lo primero, si, entiendo el error ahí.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En `unique`, cuando haces la compresión `[ x | x <- xs , recorrido x xs == 0]` estás ocultando el argumento de la función `x`.

Por ejemplo, cuando haces `unique [1, 2, 3]`, se hacen las siguientes sustituciones:

```hs
unique [1, 2, 3]
--> [x | x <- [2, 3], recorrido x [2,3] == 0]
<-- recorrido 2 [2,3] == -1
<-- recorrido 3 [2,3] == -1
--> []
```

Un modo sencillo es hacer `unique` recursiva:

```hs
unique :: [Int] -> [Int]
unique [] = []
unique (x:xs) = x : unique [ y | y <- xs, x /= y]
```

Comment: Claro, entiendo el error que marcás. Gracias por el código y la ayuda!